# Is it safe to share the entire path with a FileProvider?

Tags: android, fileprovider

I'm working on a library where I implement a FileProvider from Android Support and want to make it easy to allow the developer to share files from any of the `external-path`, `external-cache-path`, `cache-path`.  If I provide the paths myself, the question is, do I create any security concerns if I declare sharing access to the root of each of these paths like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<paths>
  <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
  <cache-path name="internal_cache" path="." />
  <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />
</paths>
```

I still need to call `getUriForFile(..)` to get the actual URI right? Is it possible for someone to guess a filename from that path in the original content uri and then access it, or does `getUriForFile` do something special for granting access to that specific file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getUriForFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#geturiforfile) returns a secure Uri for accessing that one file only. The FileProvider grants access to a single file per Uri. What you have proposed is a secure way to allow apps to access your files.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to support this?  I don't doubt you, but I'm having a hard time finding a good source to prove this... Thanks!

Comment: The `getUriForFile()` is a link to the documentation for that. It is also part of the FileProvider documentation. Read "Generating the Content URI for a File" and "Granting Temporary Permissions to a URI" They explain it really well. I have also extensively tested this in my apps. - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#GetUri